# Can Acronis True Image or Backup run multiple plans?

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

If I have 4 volumes (any configuration based on RAID or without).

I want to copy:

volume 1 to volume 3 (saved as compressed TIB)
volume 2 to volume 4 (saved as compressed TIB)

Is it possible to run both jobs simultaneously? or second one will wait until first is finished?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried only Backup 11 Windows Server. It looks like in settings I can chose only VM backup simultaneously. When I create volume based plans.. 2nd one is not running... at least it says 0% and HDD led is not active.